# Правильно ли я передаю id текстового поля в функцию для выполнения действий с этим полем?

Tags: android, kotlin

```
public lateinit var currentField: EditText
...............
i -> i.setOnFocusChangeListener { viewCurrent: View, hasFocus ->
     currentField = viewCurrent as EditText
...............
if (currentField.text.toString().isNotEmpty()) {
```

Работает, но всё же, чтобы в дальнейшем не вышла какая-то ошибка

Comment: не забывайте о `hasFocus`, сейчас в `currentField` запишется и поле, которое фокус потеряло.

Comment: это и нужно - определяю поле , которое потеряло фокус и потом работаю с ним

Comment: Так оно же перезапишется новым фокусом.

Comment: при потере фокуса проверяется условие на валидность - если ошибка - поле подкрашивается красным цветом, а фокус снова возвращается в это ошибочное поле. То есть пока не пройдет проверка на валидность - можно только закрыть или свернуть программу, дальше не двинуться. Но вы правы - возникают артефакты - подкрашиваются и другие поля (криво срабатывает замена background'a). Что с этим можно сделать?

Comment: Сменить подход, нельзя запрещать переход в поле, которое позволяет в него перейти. Лучше скрывать\деактивировать поля в которые перейти нельзя и открывать\активировать по мере доступности.

Comment: получается что надо делать "недоступными" все поля, кроме ошибочного, в котором сработало "потеря фокуса" ? какое свойство поля надо выбрать чтобы деактивировать другие поля?